# I am not able to install mysql on ubuntu after unistalling it

Tags: apt, software-installation, mysql

I  have to install MySQL in Ubuntu for a class. The first time intalling mysql it worked perfectly. 
However, I accidently ran the `sudo mysql_secure_installation` command when I wasn't supposed to. I had to delete MYSQL and reinstall it.

After reinstalling MYSQL I am getting a bunch of errors. I need a "reputation of 10" to post all of the errors I am receiving. Here is how I uninstalled MySQL:
 
`sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql-client mysql-server mysql-common` 
`sudo apt-get autoremove`
`sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql/`

Here is how I am expected to install MYSQL: 
`sudo apt-get install –f mysql-server mysql-client`

Comment: You could paste the entire log here: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Then reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

It might be the autoclean and update that make a difference.

Comment: That did not work.  It just provided many errors.  It said it did not recognize a lot of links.  For example: W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'

Comment: You may need to check your network connectivity.  Sounds like it's not reaching the servers.

Comment: I am not able to even connect to the internet.

Comment: All updates and packages are downloaded from servers on the internet.  You need to enable access at least temporarily for this.